# Игра Бинго на Java

Tags: java, массивы, ооп, arraylist

В общем, суть такая. Есть игра бинго. Играют в нее четыре человека. Нужно создать для каждого игрока карточку с 25 номерами (ну как самая обычная карточка бинго). Всего номерков 75. Нужна помощь вообще как можно это реализовать. Методы, способы и так далее. И еще, обязательная часть - нужно использовать ООП.

Я создал класс, где генерируется сама карточка с 25 числами.

```
public class BingoCard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[][] card = new int[5][5];
        ArrayList<Integer> alreadyUsed = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean valid = false;
        int tmp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < card.length; row++) {
                while (!valid) {
                    tmp = (int) (Math.random() * 15) + 1 + 15 * i;
                    if (!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)) {
                        valid = true;
                        alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
                    }
                }
                card[row][i] = tmp;
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        card[2][2] = 0;


        String title[] = {"B", "I", "N", "G", "O"};

        for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(title[i] + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int row = 0; row < card.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < card[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(card[row][col] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Теперь нужно создать класс с самой игрой и игроками. Как это можно реализовать? И еще, все выводиться в консоль, про JFrame ничего не знаю, я новичок. Принимаются любые идеи. Всем спасибо

Comment: возьмите правлиа игры, и запишите их в виде алгоритма. Ну или хотя бы словами опишите последовательность действий(алгоритм). Писать за вас несколько классов тут вряд ли кто будет, а вот если вы сами начнете и сталкиваясь с проблемой придете, вам с радостью помогут.

Comment: виктор прав. опишите алгоритм и скажите,какое именно место этого алгоритма вызывает у вас трудности и в чем эти трудности выражаются. если вы совсем не понимаете, как это реализовать - это один случай, если вы просто не понимаете, как это сделать конкретно на java - совершенно другой, а если вы что-то пишите , а оно не работает или работает неправильно - третий и т.д. чем точнее опишите проблему, тем быстрее получите ответ и тем качественней этот ответ будет